# When to maintain reference to key vs. reference to actual entity object after put operation.

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

When working with datastore entities in App Engine, people have noticed odd behavior after a put operation is performed on an entity if you choose to hold on to a reference of that entity.

For example, see [this issue](https://code.google.com/p/appengine-ndb-experiment/issues/detail?id=208) where repeated String properties mutated to _BaseValue after a put was performed.

In the ensuing discussion, in reference to a repeated String property, Guido van Rossum writes:

> "I see. We should probably document that you're not supposed to hang
>   on to the list of items for too long; there are various forms of
>   undefined behavior around that."

I get the sense from this thread that it's not a good idea to maintain reference to an entity for too long after a put, as unexpected behavior might arise.

However, when I look at the [GAE source code](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/branches/1.2.1/python/google/appengine/ext/db/__init__.py) for the `Model.get_or_insert()` method, I see the following code (docstring removed):

```
  @classmethod
  def get_or_insert(cls, key_name, **kwds):
    def txn():
      entity = cls.get_by_key_name(key_name, parent=kwds.get('parent'))
      if entity is None:
        entity = cls(key_name=key_name, **kwds)
        entity.put()
      return entity
    return run_in_transaction(txn)
```

Notice how a put operation is performed, and the entity is returned post-put. Just above, we saw an example of when this is not recommended.

Can anyone clarify when and when it is not ok to maintain a reference to an entity, post put? Guido seemed to hint that there are various scenarios when this could be a bad idea. Just curious if anyone has seen documentation on this (I cannot find any).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem described in the issue is not regarding entities, but rather lists obtained from its properties. You can hold a copy of entity as long as you like. It's just an object.

The issue is caused by some "magical" functionality provided by ndb. Let's take a look at the model definition

```
from google.appengine.ext.ndb import model

class MyModel(model.Model):
    items = model.StringProperty(repeated=True)
```

What can we say about items property?

It looks like a class attribute, but metaclass logic of model.Model transforms it into an instance attribute.

What type are these instance attributes?

They can be accessed like a list of strings, but they are more complex objects having the logic required for storing and retrieving the data from datastore, validating etc.

This "magic" works well in most cases, but sometimes it doesn't. One of the problematic cases is when you get the reference to items from the instance and try to use it after put was called. Another case, mentioned by Guido, was to pass external list to initialize items property and then try to modify this property by manipulating the external list.

**The thing to remember**: Model properties in ndb try to behave like their basic types, but they are more complex objects. You can read more about their internals in [Writing property subclasses](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/subclassprop)